# SignalR with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, signalr

Is it possible to use SignalR with LINQ instead of regular SqlCommand looking like
    @"SELECT [Field1], [Field2] FROM [dbo].[TableName]"

how i can i change code to make it work

my code is based on example from this tutorial: http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

Comment: Yes? SignalR just calls a method. There're very few restraints on what that method can contain. If you're using LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework in the project, it shouldn't be too difficult to also use it in your SignalR hub.

Comment: but calling a method is invoked by a change made in specified table ?